# Xamp Apache not starting

Tags: apache, xampp

To start off, I know there's similar threads regarding this. I followed them but can not get it to work which is why I'm opening another one.

When I'm trying to start Apache using Xamp control panel it gets stuck on "Attempting to start Apache service..". I have set the main port to 8080, SSL port to 8081. In the http.conf file I set Listen 8080 and ServerName localhost:8080.

What else is there to be done?

Comment: Look at your logs (error_log for startup errors usually).  Then without your config. file, we cannot do much.  You say you set 8081 for SSL, do you have a `Listen 8081` in your config?  For more help, post your config and error message(s).

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll take a look and post them later tonight